# Generating Correlated Random Variables following Weibull Distribution

Tags: time-series, correlation, random-generation, weibull-distribution, synthetic-data

I am working on analyzing power generation from geographically distributed wind farms. I have wind speed data that have been collected at multiple locations, but the measurement periods for different locations are different and there is limited temporal overlap between any two data sets. So, I have to generate synthetic wind data for each of these locations for simulation purposes.

I have searched in literature, but I could only find [Simulation of correlated wind speed and power variates in wind parks](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378779609002727) but it seems to be different from what I am trying to do.

My specific queries are:

1. Is there any method of transforming multiple independent random time series into correlated time series, if correlation matrix is given?
2. Is there any way of generating correlated time series, if correlation matrix and (k,c) Weibull parameters for each site are given?

Comment: Your second link is broken.

Comment: Haven't done it for the Weibull case myself, but [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718752/how-to-generate-correlated-uniform0-1-variables/32751268#32751268) may work for you.

Comment: It sounds like you want to build a multivariate distribution using the marginals you already have in the sense of measurement data, and imposing a dependence structure of your choice. If my interpretation is correct, this can be achieved by means of a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)).